# Excel macro to copy rows in certain intervals

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to write a macro that would enable me to copy rows 7206 to 7211 on to another sheet. Then continue to rows 7200 to 7205. In short reverse the order of data onto another sheet. what logic can i use in vba macro to help me achieve this?

[image]

Comment: A loop with `For i = 7206 Step -5`

Comment: Maybe start by recording a macro while copy/pasting the first couple of blocks, then see if you can modify that to add a loop as suggested by @urdearboy

Answer (score 0):

### Copy 6 Rows Backwards

Adjust the values in the constants section.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy6RowsBackwards()

    Const SourceSheet As String = "Sheet1"
    Const TargetSheet As String = "Sheet2"
    Const NumberOfRows As Long = 6
    Const FirstRow As Long = 6
    Const FirstColumn As Long = 1
    Const LastColumn As Long = 19
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "A1"

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Source As Variant, Target As Variant
    Dim Curr As Long, UB1 As Long, UB2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SourceSheet)
        Set rng = .Range(.Columns(FirstColumn), .Columns(LastColumn)) _
          .Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, FirstColumn), _
          .Cells(rng.Row, LastColumn))
    End With
    Source = rng
    Set rng = Nothing

    UB1 = UBound(Source): UB2 = UBound(Source, 2)
    ReDim Target(1 To UB1, 1 To UB2)

    Curr = UB1 + 1
    m = 1
    For i = 1 To UB1 / NumberOfRows
        Curr = Curr - NumberOfRows
        For k = 0 To NumberOfRows - 1
            For j = 1 To UB2
                Target(m, j) = Source(Curr + k, j)
            Next j
            m = m + 1
        Next k
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheet)
        With .Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(UB1, UB2)
            .Value = Target
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your data and your last date in on `Row 7206`, the first date must start on `Row 6`, with 5 rows left at the top. So, I've set this basic code to start copying at `Row 6` and end at `Row 7206`. It will loop through each cell with a date and copy the range (6 rows, 19 columns) based on your example data, then insert the copied range into the first cell on your destination sheet. Using `Insert Shift:=xlDown` each consecutive copy paste will insert the next date and range above the last one. So, the last date/range will be on top and ending with the first date/range. The data in your source sheet will not change. If you need the first 5 rows moved to the other worksheet it can be easily done. Change the worksheet names as needed. If you are going to use another workbook, then you will have to change `ThisWorkbook` to the other workbooks name.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For x = 6 To 7206 Step 6
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AllData").Cells(x, 1).Resize(6, 19).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```