# Macro in Excel to copy rows in certain intervals

Tags: excel, vba

I need this code : [Excel macro to copy rows in certain intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826045/excel-macro-to-copy-rows-in-certain-intervals/74317606#74317606) modified
The part with GMalc code. I have managed to modify and copy side-by-side the 96 range of rows i need. But they are backwards. I need them to be arranged forwards. I mean from B1 to B2784 in my case?

[image: Source Column]

I tried the code :

```
Sub Daily_Separation()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For x = 1 To 2784 Step 96
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Separation").Cells(x, 2).Resize(96, 1).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next x
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

The result is :
[image: AC column must be A column]

I need to be arranged from B1 downward, not from B2784.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting from the left, so the latest (largest) values will be in column 1.
I suggest: (and search "avoiding copy/paste")

```
Sub Daily_Separation()
  Dim iRow&, iCol&
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b1") = "A" ' demonstration data
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2") = "B"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b3") = "C"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b4") = "D"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b5") = "E"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b6") = "F"
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  iCol = 1
  For iRow = 1 To 5 Step 2
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 2).Resize(2, 1).Copy _ 
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, iCol)
    iCol = iCol + 1
  Next iRow
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, thank you for this suggestion, but i don't quite get it. 
At the end i need 30/31 Columns, with 96 rows each, representing a month long data.
Each 96 range period is a day. The macro i modified is working but arranging columns from the back to front. I need to be arranged from B1 to B1, not from B1 to AF1.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it either.

Comment: OK! "my" code arrange column B parts of 96 rows (see first picture above), as last column - AC column (see the second picture above) from the source Sheet. I need the part, listed in AC column, to be listed in column A in the Sheet2, the part listed in AB column to be in B column and so on. 
In the second picture every single piece of 96 rows are arranged backwards - the first part from the Source Sheet is the last in the Destination Sheet (AC column)

Comment: 96 Rows and 30/31 columns is too much to work with.  Can you describe your desires in 5 rows and 3 columns?  Again, sorry I don't get it.